# How can I apply a transparent color to a cell in XSLXWriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to create a format that has an alpha, i.e. a transparency
For yellow with no alpha one does this:

```
yellow_format = workbook.add_format()
yellow_format.set_bg_color('#FFFF00')
```

I tried this:

```
yellow_format = workbook.add_format()
yellow_format.set_bg_color('#FFFF0088')
```

where 88 would be a 50% transparency, but it gives black. I guess if it can't figure out what the color it is then it defaults to black.

Is this possible?

Comment: [The documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html#colors) says that only #RRGGBB and some named colors will work, and doesn't mention anything about transparency. Are you sure .xlsx files support transparent formats? I can't find any way in excel to set transparency of a cell's background color, just its RGB color. It looks like certain shapes and charts can have transparency but I personally can't find anything related to cells themselves having a transparent background.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a thought of how this might be accomplished: Get the current background color of a cell, then OR it (or something like that) with my yellow  to get a combined color and call `set_bg_color(combined_color)`. I don't see anything like `cell.get_bg_color()` though.

Comment: But then, that's why its called `XlsxWriter` not `XlsxReader` I guess.

Comment: @RandomDavis: if you want to put your comment in the form of an answer, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(re-posting my comment as an answer)

[The documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html#colors) says that only `#RRGGBB` and some named colors will work, and doesn't mention anything about transparency. I also don't think .xlsx files support transparent formats. I can't find any way in excel to set transparency of a cell's background color, just its RGB color. It looks like certain shapes and charts can have transparency but I personally can't find anything related to cells themselves having a transparent background.

My recommendation would be to, if you can, get the color of the cell beforehand (since you're using XLSXWriter you're likely setting the color anyway at some point), and then mix the color with whichever one you want, using your desired transparency.

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter and this is correct. Excel doesn't support transparency in cell colours so XlsxWriter cannot support it. Where transparency is supported in Excel, such as in charts, XlsxWriter tries to support it.

Comment: @jmcnamara thanks for commenting, that's as definitive of an answer as it gets!

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same question and found that for some format cases there is an "transparency" option which just takes a number for percentage:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-formatting-line-1